# highcharts dynamic spline with fluid size issue in table

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Hello I use the highcharts dynamic spline.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/)

It is automatically changing the width size when users change the browser size.

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

But here I have a problem.

When I use this div in the table it does not work.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <td><div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The chart prevents the container from shrinking. The pure CSS
>   workaround is to set position:absolute and width: 100% on the
>   container, then it won't affect the layout of the table cell

Just change this in your div:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; width:100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto; position: absolute;">
```

and add this in your td:

```
 <td style="vertical-align: top;" >
```

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9WhbG/1/

You can see here for more information: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1157